Visualize the DNN model with streamlit from colab
I am new to data science and this is on my coursework. I am trying to cast my developed DNN model to webapp from streamlit. But it is not displaying my app after running following steps

installing streamlit
!pip install -q streamlit


running code in colab cell
 %%writefile /content/drive/MyDrive/Coursework-02/src/app.py
 import streamlit as st
 import numpy as np
 import tensorflow as tf
 from tensorflow import keras

 # Load the trained model
 model = keras.models.load_model('/content/drive/MyDrive/Coursework-02/src/ecg_model.h5')

 # Function to preprocess input data
 def preprocess_data(data):
     return processed_data

 # Function to make predictions
 def predict(data):
     processed_data = preprocess_data(data)
     prediction = model.predict(processed_data)
     return prediction

 # Streamlit web app
 def app():
     st.title('ECG Anomaly Detection')

     input_data = st.text_area('Enter ECG Signal Data (comma-separated)', '')

     data = np.array([float(val) for val in input_data.split(',')])

     if st.button('Predict'):
         prediction = predict(data)
         st.write(f'Prediction: {prediction}')

 if __name__ == "__main__":
     app()


Finally
!streamlit run /content/drive/MyDrive/Coursework-02/src/app.py &>/dev/null&



But I am getting site can't reached error from this. Can any expert help me to identify what I've missed?
